# Take data from one div and insert into another section of page

Tags: jquery

What would be the best solution to this ... I want to take the 3rd content div's image filename, link, and text), and duplicate it as the first entry in the old section. Basically duplicating the data contents, but using the div structure from the old section. The differences in structure as you can see are the image path (one using featured, and the other being boxart), and the imgframenew and posterimage div.

If you need me to clarify let me know as this is a little abstract, and difficult for me to describe easily in writing.

```
<div class="new">

<div class="content"><div class="imgframenew">
<div class="posterimage" style="background:url(/media/images/featured/pic1.jpg);"></div></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link1/">Example 1</a></div></div>

<div class="content"><div class="imgframenew">
<div class="posterimage" style="background:url(/media/images/featured/pic2.jpg);"></div></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link2/">Example 2</a></div></div>

<div class="content"><div class="imgframenew">
<div class="posterimage" style="background:url(/media/images/featured/pic3.jpg);"></div></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link3/">Example 3</a></div></div>

</div><div class="old">

<!-- Duplicate 3rd div content from above, here, but using the div structure from below -->

<div class="content"><div class="imgframe" style="background:url(/media/images/boxart/pic4.jpg);"></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link4">Example 4</a></div></div>

<div class="content"><div class="imgframe" style="background:url(/media/images/boxart/pic5.jpg);"></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link5">Example 5</a></div></div>

<div class="content"><div class="imgframe" style="background:url(/media/images/boxart/pic6.jpg);"></div>
<div class="title"><a rel="/media/link6">Example 6</a></div></div>
```

Comment: isn't the third div from "new" the same content as the third div from "old"?

Comment: I see you added a new question with my code, if you're going to use it please take a moment to mark the answer here as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the corresponding image and link from the `.new` section, then you have two options, you can either use `clone()` to duplicate an entry inside `.old` and update the corresponding values or you can create a new div with the `.old` structure "by hand".

Here's an example using the `clone()` method:

```
var $toCopy = $('.new .content:eq(2)'); //get the third element from .new
var $newDiv = $('.old .content:first').clone().prependTo('.old'); //duplicate the first element from .old to get the structure

var oldBg = $toCopy.find('.posterimage').css('background-image').replace('featured','boxart'); //get the background
$newDiv.find('.imgframe').css('background-image',oldBg); //set the bg
$newDiv.find('a').replaceWith($toCopy.find('a').clone()); //replace link
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybBkQ/2/)**

Comment: Not really, this script only works for the structure you posted, no one can really give you a general solution since it will be dependant on the structure of your divs and the attributes you wish to replace, right now the error you get is because either there's no div with the posterimage class or it has no background image set

Comment: @Jrags87 how are you handling the navigation? there's no href in your example